# Rspec failed for Javascript tests headless chrome on Github actions

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, rspec-rails

I am using Github action to run Rspec tests which have many feature tests with few javascript. All other test passing but Javascript one are failing. Is there way to run rspec capaybara tests with javascript using github actions.
Following is my capybara helper configuration

```
Capybara.server = :puma, { Silent: true }

Capybara.register_driver :chrome_headless do |app|
  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1400,1400')

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome_headless

# Setup rspec
RSpec.configure do |config|
  #config.before(:each, type: :system) do
  #  driven_by :rack_test
  #end

  config.before(:each, type: :system, js: true) do
    driven_by :chrome_headless
  end
end
```

I am getting error for Javascript test errors

```
2) Visitor signs up with valid email and password
     Failure/Error: width = page.evaluate_script("$('#LeftNavPaneContent').width();")
     Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
       Capybara::Driver::Base#evaluate_script
     # ./spec/features/javascript/navigation_toggle_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  3) Login and out it should redirect to the dashboard and allow you to log out
     Failure/Error: page.driver.browser.navigate.refresh
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `navigate' for #<Capybara::RackTest::Browser:0x00005589b2afd070>
     # ./spec/features/login_logout/login_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Following is my action file for chromedriver

```
run:  |
  sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
  sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
.
.
.
  run: |
   export DISPLAY=:99
   chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hut &
   sudo Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280/1024/24 > /dev/null 2>&1 & # optional
   bundle exec rspec
```

These tests locally pass and no issue. I think it is because these have Javascripts inside test I am using `js: true` but seem it is not working properly. Any help

Comment: Are your tests actually specified as system specs (type metdata on the spec)?  From their directory location they may be being set as feature specs rather than system..

Comment: I added type feature but still same error coming.

Comment: you should be adding type system if you want them to be system tests (which is what you’ve configured for in your rspec before block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used following configuration in my `rails_helper` and it worked.

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
      chromeOptions: { args: %w[--headless --disable-gpu] },
      'goog:loggingPrefs': {
          browser: 'ALL'
      }
    )

  options = ::Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new

  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1400,1400')

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :chrome,
      desired_capabilities: capabilities,
      options: options
    )
end

Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
```